# how to Call volley with recycleview inside class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I hope someone out there can help me solve my problem with volley library with recycle view in kotlin.

How can I connect this class with volley library and looping the data like last loop below. also i have error in (Instantiating the RequestQueue) I try several times but unfortunately I couldn't

here is my api: https://adeega.xisaabso.online/welcome.php

```
package com.example.emoney

import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.example.emoney.models.BlogPost

import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

class DataSource{

companion object{

    fun createDataSet(): ArrayList<BlogPost>{
        val list = ArrayList<BlogPost>()

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val url = "https://adeega.xisaabso.online/welcome.php"


        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.


                try {
                    //val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
                    /*
                    for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val jsonObject      = JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i))
                        //var id              = jsonObject.get("id")
                        var username        = jsonObject.get("Username")
                        //var secondName      = jsonObject.get("SecondName")
                        textViewResult.text = username.toString()

                        //println(jsonObject)

                        //Toast.makeText(this, firstName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        //println(id.toString() + " - " +firstName.toString())
                    }
                    */

                } catch(e: Exception) {
                    println("Error")
                }

            },
            { println("That didn't work!"))

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)


                

        for (i in 1..50) {
            list.add(
                BlogPost(
                    "Congratulations!",
                    "You made it to the end of the course!\r\n\r\nNext we'll be building the REST API!",
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchtabian/Blog-Images/master/digital_ocean.png",
                    "Sally"
                )

            )

            return list
        }




    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to learn it properly, your code is not making any sense since you are calling an API in class and within companion scope.

Comment: i can call an api in the main_activity but can not in other activity, can you help me?

Comment: sure, kindly add your complete code here.

Comment: Your code is just not readable, can you focus on the snippet that giving issue? or you can just share your full project if it's allowed so I can take a look into it?

Comment: Mr wale, the problem is in first section especially, i want to call volley library in recycler view and looping data from my api

Comment: is there any one?

Comment: is there any one?